# Python script crashes when I input an integer

Tags: python

I was trying to make a simple dice in py, and I tried to make so you can change the amount of sides the dice has and if it's left empty, to default to 6. But when I input something, it crashes.

```
import keyboard #Import keyboard stuff like enter (pip install keyboard)
import random #Import random stuff
import time

sides = 1
sidesSelect = input("Amount of sides the dice has. If empty, 6: ")
is_non_empty= bool(sidesSelect)
if is_non_empty is False:
    sides = 6
else:
    sides = sidesSelect

time.sleep(0.5)

while True: 
    nmb = random.randint(1,sides) #Get random integer
    print("The dice rolled ", nmb) 
    input('Press enter to roll the dice again') #Ask if you want to throw again
    time.sleep(random.uniform(0.2,0.8))
```

I already tried changing == is, and nothing happened

```
if is_non_empty is false:
```

Comment: Thanks, it fixed my problem. bool(sideSelect) was there to check if they input something in the input, although i'll try to remove it

Comment: What does "it crashes" mean exactly? Please always include detailed information on the problem you are encountering

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One issue your code has is it is trying to use the input directly without taking care of the type.

`input()` returns a string, so it has to be converted to proper type before using it in `randint`

Try something like this.

```
#python3

sidesSelect = int(input("Amount of sides the dice has. If empty, 6: ") or "6")

nmb = random.randint(1, sidesSelect) #Get random integer
```

[input()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input)

Answer (score 0):

You should instead convert it to an float, with `float(input(...))`, and then check to make sure that it is not NaN with `math.isnan()`, and then if it is a valid number, convert it to an int and continue on.

```py
import math
sidesSelect = float(input('Enter sides') or 'nan')
if math.isnan(sidesSelect):
    sides = 6
else:
    sides = int(sidesSelect)
#rest of code
```

Because float(invalid) will return nan, you can see if the number entered is valid or not, and then if it is, convert to an int. Otherwise, you can use your default and then continue on.

Comment: I tried putting that piece of code into mine, but when I test it without any numbers, it brings me this error https://pastebin.com/ctT8PS83

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: So if you change the sidesSelect line to  `sidesSelect = float(input('Enter sides:') or 'nan')`, then it will be correct. But if you are doing that, then you might as well go with the other answer.